# How is the quotient of a graded ring itself graded?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, graded-rings

I know little ring theory, but have the following general question:

If $R$ is a $G$-graded ring ($R = \bigoplus_{k∈G}R_k$ where $R_iR_j ⊆ R_{i+j}$) and $I ⊆ R$ is an ideal ($I$ is closed under addition and $RI ⊆ I$), then how can one determine the grading of the quotient $R/I$ in general? What are the relevant properties of $I$?

I’m asking this question with the following examples in mind:
The tensor algebra $\mathrm TV$ (which is naturally a ring) is $ℤ$-graded, and…

- The exterior algebra $\bigwedge(V) = \mathrm TV\big/⟨⊗⟩$ is the quotient of the tensor algebra over the ideal generated by elements of the form $⊗$ for $ ∈ V$. The exterior algebra itself is also $ℤ$-graded (and hence also $ℤ_2$-graded).
- The Clifford algebra $Cl(V, q) = \mathrm TV\big/⟨⊗ - q()⟩$ is a quotient with respect to an ideal which identifies vector squares $⊗$ with their “norm square” $q()$. The Clifford algebra is $ℤ_2$-graded (but not $ℤ$-graded).

I have a vague hope that there might be a sense in which, if $Γ(R)$ is the “maximal” monoid for which $R$ is $Γ(R)$-graded, then $Γ(R/I) ≅ Γ(R)/Γ(I)$ for some suitable definition of $Γ(I)$.

Is there a way to determine the grading of $R/I$ from the grading of $R$ and $I$ without resorting to inspecting $R/I$?

Comment: The ideal $I$ needs to be homogeneous (i.e., to satisfy $I = \bigoplus_{k \in G} \left(I\cap R_k\right)$) in order for the quotient to have a natural grading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you are looking for is the ideal $I$ being *homogeneous* (or equivalently, *graded*).
A homogeneous ideal is an ideal generated by homogeneous elements, i.e., elements belonging to some $R_k$.
Equivalently, an ideal $I$ is homogeneous if it is $G$-graded, $I = \bigoplus_{k ∈ G} I ∩ R_k$ (see [this post](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/graded-ideals/) or [proposition 2.1](https://math.unl.edu/%7Etmarley1/905notes.pdf) for why these are equivalent).

The quotient $R/I$ by a homogeneous ideal has a natural grading: i.e., if $R$ and $I$ are $G$-graded, then $R/I$ is $G$-graded.

The exterior algebra is $ℤ$-graded since it is a quotient by a $ℤ$-graded ideal. The Clifford algebra is only $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded because the defining ideal is only $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded: with respect to this $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading the ideal is homogeneously generated by $⊗ - q() ∈ (\mathrm TV)_0.$

Comment: Ah! So to make sure I understand: the polynomial ring $ℝ[x]/(x^3 - 1)$ is $ℤ_3$-graded because the ideal $⟨x^3 - 1⟩$ is not homogeneous with respect to the natural $ℤ$-grading of $R[x]$, but _is_ homogeneous with respect to the $ℤ_3$-grading?

Comment: So really, a statement like [“the quotient $R/I$ of graded ring $R$ with graded/homogeneous ideal $I$ is a graded ring”](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3774827/126321) means they admit the **same** grading; i.e., if $R$ and $I$ are $G$-graded then $R/I$ is $G$-graded. @Serge, is that correct? (I previously thought this phrasing only meant that $R/I$ admitted some _unspecified_ grading, hence this duplicate question.)

Comment: @Jollywatt. I wouldn't say the 'same' grading, but that a grading on the quotient is naturally unduced from the grading on the original ring. The k-th graded piece will be $R_k/(I\cap R_k)$.